# Meteor Fibers error - across different versions of Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-fibers, fibers

I have 3 meteor applications all at different versions

- App#1 (v1.2.1)
- App#2 (v1.3.2.1)
- App#3 (v1.4.1)

Apps #1 & #3 are running fine. 
But App#2 gets the following error message

> module.js:340  Error: Cannot find module 'fibres'

In desperation, I upgraded App#2 to v1.3.3, and it now runs ok.
But now App#1 is getting the same error message.
Can someone explain to me why and what to do?
I've reinstalled Meteor from scratch but it hasn't made a difference.
Any help would be massively appreciated as this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fibres module, but have a look at this

> meteor users please read this If you're trying to get meteor running
>   and you ended up at this page you're probably doing something wrong.
>   Please uninstall all versions of NodeJS and Meteor, then start over.
>   See [meteor#5124](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5124) for more information.

More on this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers